# One to Many Database Table Relationship

Tags: sql-server, database

I do have two tables from the database..

```
Consultation Table
-ConsultationNo -PK
-PatientNo -FK
-Diagnosis
-Etc...


VitalSign Table
-VitalSignNo -PK
-Weight
-Height
-HeartRate
-BloodPressure
-Etc
```

I need to join these two tables like this..

```
Consultation Table
-ConsultationNo -PK
-PatientNo -FK
**-VitalSignNo** -FK
-Diagnosis
-Etc...
```

But sometimes, my VitalSign Table will not accept any values, therefore the relationship between those two tables would not be enforced, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Use an outer join like so...

```
Select * from Consultation
Left join VitalSign on (Consultation.ConsultationNo = vitalsign.ConsultationNo)
```

You will get all rows from consultation, and the matching rows from Vitalsign. When there are no rows in Vitalsign all those columns will come back null, but you will still get the consultation rows.

This might not be exactly right for your situation because the table structure in your question doesn't look complete. That, is you didn't have a foreign key in either table referencing the PK of the other.

Comment: Thanks for your input! But what I need to ask is, How I may be able to INSERT a one complete row in the ConsultationTable if there is no record at VItalSign

Comment: I don't understand. You will need to edit your question to be more clear what you are trying to do and provide examples. I don't understand from your comment what you mean at all.